# Calendar repeat day of week events

Tags: iphone, calendar

I need to repeat bi-weekly events. This is on either the second Wednesday of the month and the first and third Thursdays. When I specify biweekly events and there is a fifth Thursday, that is included. As a result, the first Thursday of the next month is skipped and chooses the second and fourth Thursday.

Can this be done with iOS calendar or a third party app?

Comment: "Either second Wednesday and ? 1st and 3d Thursday, does not read right. Either is usually followed by "or" not by "and"! Please check your question. Do you mean Either on 2nd Wednesday or 1st and 3d Thursday.

Comment: strictly speaking, if any 5th Thursday should be ignored, then it's not 'biweekly' (a term I hate because there's no way to specify whether it's every 2 weeks or twice a week;), it's twice a month.

Answer (score 1):

I had to program a bi-monthly event. I could NOT find any way of reliably doing so.

In the end I programmed 2 (identical) events, one on the 2nd Thursday, one on the 4th.

You could do similar with 3 events.